# How to compare two columns whether they are equal in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to compare two columns and return the count value by grouping.

I've tried the below aggregation:

```
Activity.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$phasename',
            data: {
                '$push': {
                    Complete:
                        {
                            $cond: [
                                {$eq: ["$plannedEndDate", "$actualEndDate"]},
                                0,
                                1
                            ]
                        }
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            Complete1: "$data.Complete"
        }
    }
]);
```

But its not taking the column values, if I hardcode then this works fine.

please suggest how to fix this.thanks

my sample collection is ,

```
 {
    "_id": "5e0dd8628003b63cf48eb2b9",
    "text": "act1",
    "incumbentUser": "Sam",
    "vendorUser": "Sam",
    "plannedEndDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
    "phasename": "Knowledge Transfer",
    "actualEndDate": "2010-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e0dd8628003b63cf48eb2b8",
    "text": "act1",
    "incumbentUser": "Sam",
    "vendorUser": "Sam",
    "plannedEndDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
    "phasename": "Analysis",
    "actualEndDate": "2010-01-03T00:00:00.000+00:00"
  }
```

Comment: Can you post a single document as reference?

Comment: Works as expected: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ShschpQ8Y3f

Comment: but it returns  "Complete1": [] for me in the result set.

Comment: as @tomslabbaert said, provide sample data

Comment: i have updated in the question section.